# Karate -- JSON Response Parsing

Tags: json, karate

Below is the JSON response I receive when I am hitting a particular web service:

```
[
  {
    "sId" : "0001",
    "sName" : "abc1",
    "sPlace" : "abc11"
  }, {
    "sId" : "0002",
    "sName" : "abc2",
    "sPlace" : "abc12"
  }, {
    "sId" : "0003",
    "sName" : "abc3",
    "sPlace" : "abc13"
  }, {
    "sId" : "0004",
    "sName" : "abc4",
    "sPlace" : "abc14"
  }
]
```

I don't know which index has my expected values (I need to validate multiple values after identifying which has `sId == '0003'`), this is dynamic. Don't want to user hard coded value. 
And match `response.[3].sId == '0003'`
because this will be changed next time.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. How can I pass response to java code and get the array index which having `sId == '0003'` so that I can use this index to validate?
2. How can I pass a variable value as an array index in response?

The code below is not working.

```
def ind = Java.type('karate.Utility.FindIndex') 
response.['#ind'].sId == '0003'
```

Comment: Can you get what you want with [JsonPath Filters](https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters)? As far as I understand your question, you may not need the index itself.

Answer (score 2):

karate uses json-path which allows writing conditions to read data from JSON.

example:

```
* def sId = "0003"
* def sValue = karate.jsonPath(response, "$[?(@.sId == '" + sId + "')]")
* match sValue[0] == {"sId" : "0003","sName" : "abc3","sPlace" : "abc13"}
```

now if there is a match in sId on the response JSON array, all such matches will be returned.

> No need to do * match sValue[0].sId == "0003" as this is your filter
>   criteria

[More about JSON path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

[online JSON path evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/)

[karate doc refernce](https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Yes it is working for me.